# Turn off Windows 7 Fingerprint logon

Tags: windows-7, fingerprint

Annoyingly, I can't seem to train Windows 7 with my fingerprints. (Can do one or two fingers, but mostly I find it useless)

I'd like to make the login screen go straight to letting me type in my password, bypassing any attempt at capturing fingerprints.

Any idea how I can turn the fingerprint login screen off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control the fingerprint capturing options in the control panel:
Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Biometric Devices

You can turn on/off requirements for fingerprints for local (on by default) and domain (off by default) logins or just turn off fingerprints in their entirety.

[image: Image from blog.brainlitter.com]

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I tried searching google, and I tried navigating around control panel.. but I kept going to 'Security' - thinking biometric logon settings would be there...

Answer (score 4):

Click the right mouse button on the "Computer" shortcut on the Desktop and then "Properties".

On the left side, find and click on the "Device Manager". From the list, find and click "Biometric Devices". Double click on "Validity Sensor" and use 'disable'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe deactivation/uninstalling the Fingerprint Reader in the Hardware Control Panel will work.

Comment: This was the route I took on my Acer TravelMate 6593.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to not use this login method anymore, you can disable the fingerprint device:

- Open the Start Menu and go to
  **Control Panel**
- Click *System and Security*, and under
  System click **Device Manager**
- **Or**, Use your Run... box and type
  *devmgmt.msc*
- **Or**, Use the Start Menu Search Box and
  type *device manager*, locate the
  executable on the results list and
  fire it up

Once inside the Device Manager, locate your fingerprint reader

1. Right-Click it and Select
   **Properties**
2. Under the Driver Tab, click the
   **Disable Button** and confirm your selection